# Replace text in first line of tab-delimited file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a tab delimited file that has 10k+ rows. I need to change a specific field of the first(header) record to a specific value.. 
I am using the following script, but it messes up the format.

```
$contents = Get-Content $PATH -Delimiter "`t"
$contents[1] = 'Replaced Text'
$contents | Out-File $PATH
```

I can see that the format will mess up, but i am not sure how to keep the file exactly as it is and just change what I need to.
Also, I would like to know if there is an efficient way.. Because i am just concerned with the first line of the file.

I tried a different approach, it works "ok" but introduces extra blank lines after each line:

```
$content = Get-Content $PATH -Delimiter "`n"
$content | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.ReadCount -le 1) { 
      $_ -replace 'A','B' 
    } else { 
      $_ 
    } 
  } | 
  Set-Content $PATH
```

Comment: The header is the first line yes? What about the line are you replacing. A->B or replacing the whole header? Also not sure what you mean by _I can see that the format will mess up,_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
$content = {Get-Content $PATH}.Invoke() 
$content[0].Replace('A','B') | Set-Content $PATH
$content.RemoveAt(0)
$content | Add-Content $PATH
```

Using .`invoke()` on the script block causes `Get-Content` to return a collection rather than an array, which simplifies removing the first element.